# RabbitMQ Boot failed. Getting logger error

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to run rabbitmq server on my mac and i keep getting this error:

Starting broker...Logger - error: {removed_failing_handler,rabbit_log}

BOOT FAILED

I have tried reinstalling it several times and even logged into local host but see the same error.[image]

Comment: Note the `Config files: (none)` you might need to configure your settings to match the system: https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it. Ran these commands to fully uninstall RabbitMQ (vhosts, users too).

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove rabbitmq-server
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove rabbitmq-server
```

Then after I reinstalled everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you are running it on Big Sur- it keeps on giving errors to me that I didn't get previously.

Try `pip3 uninstall rabbitmq-server` then `pip3 install rabbitmq server`- that worked for me.